# Adding struct containing not copyable/moveable object to std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have this MCVE:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct foo
{
    int intValue;
    std::atomic_bool bar;

    foo( int intValue ) : intValue( intValue ) {};
};

std::map<std::string, foo> myMap;

int main()
{
    myMap.emplace( "0",  1234 );
}
```

It does not compile because `std::atomic` is neither copyable nor movable.

**My question:**

How can I add a class containing a not copyable/moveable object to a `std::map` container?

Comment: You really should not use `const char*` as a key to a mapping. That's because it will be the *pointer* that is the key, not what it points to.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This is an `MCVE`. In my real project it is `std::string` and `foo` is much more complicated. I wanted to make it really very small. Thx

Comment: For future reference, when creating a MCVE, please don't add possible other sources of errors, as that will only confuse us. Actually *create* an MCVE, as close to your actual program as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
myMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple("0"),
              std::forward_as_tuple(1234));
```

?

Comment: @AlBundy You'd have heard about it if you'd _read_ and _studied_ the documentation for `std::map` as part of planning for this task...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) has the example but - this I checked first due to Google sort order - [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/) does **not**.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no need for such comments imho

Comment: @M.M: Teach a man to fish, mate. It's the single most helpful thing you'll do all day. Thanks for your constructive contribution to this thread, though (can't believe you came here _just_ to say that - no need for such comments imho)